# In Grails g:select, using an enum, display the enum keys, but use the values as the options' values

Tags: grails, drop-down-menu, enums, key

I wanted to use a g:select tag to produce a select box where the keys of the enum are displayed to the user, while the values of the enum are passed when the form is submitted, using the following enum:

```
public enum LetterRange {
    ABCD("a-d"),
    EFGH("e-h"),
    IJKLM("i-m"),

    final String value

    AccessLevel(String value) { this.value = value }

    String toString() { value }
    String getKey() { name() }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the LetterRange enum:

```
public enum LetterRange {
    ABCD("a-d"),
    EFGH("e-h"),
    IJKLM("i-m"),

    final String value

    AccessLevel(String value) { this.value = value }

    String toString() { value }
    String getKey() { name() }
}
```

...like so in the 'g:select' tag:

```
<g:select id="letterRange" name="letterRange" from="${LetterRange}" 
        noSelection="['':'Select Range...']" optionValue="key" required=""/>
```

...which produced the following HTML on the page:

```
<select id="batchRange" name="batchRange">
    <option value="a-d">ABCD</option>
    <option value="e-h">EFGH</option>
    <option value="i-m">IJKLM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i just copied your code to test and getting this error... `Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/deliveryInstruction/create.gsp:22] Error executing tag <g:form>: [views/deliveryInstruction/create.gsp:18] Error executing tag <g:select>: No such property: key for class: LetterRange Possible solutions: id, all` Any idea why? Thanks!!

Comment: @AlwaysANovice Please post your enum as and your gsp code

Answer (score 0):

*I usually put my enum value on message.properties*, this way I get the flexibility of adding any lang translation, also purpose you are looking.

So to do that I make my enum implement the **MessageSourceResolvable** class.

e.g ( [source](http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/03/internationalizing-domain-classes-and.html) )

```
package com.mycompany

enum Season implements org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable {
    SPRING, SUMMER, AUTUMN, WINTER

    Object[] getArguments() { [] as Object[] }

    String[] getCodes() {
        ["${getClass().name}.${name()}"] as String[]
    }

    String getDefaultMessage() { name() }
}
```

message.properties

```
com.mycompany.Season.SPRING=Spring
com.mycompany.Season.SUMMER=Summer
com.mycompany.Season.AUTUMN=Autumn
com.mycompany.Season.WINTER=Winter
```

Gsp

```
<g:select  required="${com.mycompany.Season.values}"/>
```

which will give you an Html like this:

```
<select>
   <option value = "SPRING"> Spring </option>
   <option value = "SUMMER"> Summer </option>
   <option value = "AUTUMN"> Autumn </option>
   <option value = "WINTER"> Winer </option>
</select>
```